# What does "access to disposed closure" mean here?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, closures, resharper

Why does Resharper warn me about "access to disposed closure" in the following code sample:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@temp", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    Action<string> action = str =>
        {
            command.Parameters["@temp"].Value = string.Empty;
        };
}
```

I don't use delegate outside `using` statement... How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing `command` in `action`, you can use `action` in somewhere else then in `using` and `reference` to disposed `command`.

Resharper is telling you that you can access to disposed closure, because using action outside `using` will cause that. Avoid using disposable object like that, of course it will throw `NullReferenceException`, but it can be difficult to find the real problem.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but won't it throw an `ObjectDisposedException` and not a NRE?

Answer (score 6):

This code:

```
Action<string> action = str =>
{
    command.Parameters["@temp"].Value = string.Empty;
};
```

defines a delegate variable *action* that uses *command*. A delegate is a method definition that can be passed around as a variable and called somewhere else using *action.Invoke()*. *Command* is a disposable closure.

The reason Resharper flags this is because this code does not directly indicate at what point in time this delegate will actually be invoked. It is possible, in principle, that the definition of the delegate will be around (and will be invoked) after *command* has been disposed.

Resharper 8.1, the most recent version as of this writing, is not able to determine that this delegate cannot really be invoked from somewhere else.